# PHP outputting numbers in user-submitted date field

Tags: php, html, date

I'm very new to coding and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong!

I'm making a code where I want php to display what the user puts in my html date input boxes:

```
<input type="date" name="dati[]" value="Diagnosis Date" />
```

to

```
<input type="date" name="datii[]" value="Diagnosis Date" />
```

Here's my php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['dati'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['dati'] as $dati);
    foreach ($_POST['datii'] as $datii);
       echo "Diagnosis from: " . $dati . " to " . $datii;   
}
```

The output is how I want it: "Diagnosis from: 1/1/2015 to 1/2/2015" or something similar, but my problem comes when the user doesn't enter a date (because they don't have to)

In my output, I always have "Diagnosis from: to "

How do I get rid of this??

Thanks!

Comment: you can use required in your HTML or javascript for validation.But the question is if the users dont enter a value what do you want to display,if anything?

Comment: What do you want for output when the user doesn't enter anything?

Comment: if empty do this, else do that.

Comment: when the user doesn't enter anything I would just like it to do nothing

Comment: There is no point of using the foreach loops like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest this:

```
<input type="date" name="dati" value="Diagnosis Date" /> 
<input type="date" name="datii" value="Diagnosis Date" />


if(!empty($_POST['dati']) && !empty($_POST['datii'])) {
       echo "Diagnosis from: " . filter_var($_POST['dati'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); . "
 to " . filter_var($_POST['datii'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);   
}
```

**added filters to be super safe, thanks @james R

there is no need to make the fields dati,datii in to a multidimensional array (by adding [] to the name), therefore no need for the foreach loop (which wasn't needed really even if they were  multidimensional )

Comment: I would also do it like this, of course keeping in mind good practices of sanitizing any data users will submit.  Keep things nice and simple :)